# Calling RingCentral Call-Log API using the JS-SDK

Tags: javascript, calllog, ringcentral

I am using the below function to test the API Call using the JS SDK. What I am getting back in the console log is as below. Can you please check my code and let me know what is the issue here.

The response returned by this API is: `[object Object]`

The response JSON returned by this API is: `[object Object]`

```
app.get('/log', function(req, res) {

var authData = rcsdk.platform().auth().data();
rcsdk.platform().auth().setData(authData);
token_json = authData['access_token'] ? 
JSON.stringify(authData.access_token, null, ' ') : '';
response = token_json;

console.log("Before the/account/~/extension/~/presence");

rcsdk.platform().get('/account/~/extension/~/call-
log').then(function(apiResponse){
// If you want the response object
console.log("The response returned by this API is : " + 
apiResponse.response());
   // If you want the response object as JSON
console.log("The response JSON returned by this API is : " + 
apiResponse.json());
}); 

console.log("Outside the API Request");

res.render('index', {
authorize_uri: rcsdk.platform().authUrl({
 brandId: process.env.RC_APP_BRAND_ID,        // optional
  redirectUri: process.env.RC_APP_REDIRECT_URL // optional if 1 
configured
}),
redirect_uri: process.env.RC_APP_REDIRECT_URL,
token_json: token_json,
dibyendu_roy: response
});

    // Render home page with params

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to achieve here. Why you get the `authData` from the `rcsdk.platform` then set it back with the `setData()`?

Where do you instantiate the SDK?

Comment: Hey Paco , this is not what I was actually asking about. I was mainly interested to print the apiResponse.json() from the API Call. But I got the solution, it was just the stringify conversion that I needed. But thanks for responding. Ignore the get/set Data piece.